# Visual Studio 2015 checks out the solution at build time

Tags: visual-studio, solution

After upgrading from Visual Studio 2013 web site projects to Visual Studio 2015 web site projects (NOT web application projects), every time the project builds it checks out the solution file and a diff doesn't show any changes to the solution file.

We are also running ReSharper Ultimate 10.0.1.  The Visual Studio edition is the enterprise, if that makes any difference.

Comment: I have the same issue after the last update of VS 2015 (the second update 3) my tfs is 2013 (12.0.21106.0). I supposed that the problem comes that tfs see the configuration in the suo file and now VS update the configuration inside .vs hidden folder. But i am not sure. is your tfs 2013?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Deleting the hidden folder ".vs"  in the same directory as the solution file fixed the issue.